# NPM / gyp error when installing redis

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

[image]

> Full error/warning log: http://pastebin.com/xNjC4FDr

I had problem as well when I tried to install MongoDB, I have made SO question of it but, that was only warnings, so I could ignore it. But this time it's not only warnings, but also red error.

What do I have to do? Is my Nodejs messed up because I've installed Visual Studio Tools for NodeJS in the past? Or is this normal behavior? What can I do about this, I prefer not to see errors/warnings when I install something on NPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [hiredis does not support Windows](https://github.com/redis/hiredis-node/blob/d01e803cc8088dea3b697da95511ebf6d7f46813/README.md#windows) currently. The link to the Windows-compatible fork in the hiredis readme seems to be outdated (last commit in 8/2013 as of this writing), so you may be out of luck.

However `hiredis` is not required by the `redis` module, it's an optional dependency that just makes parsing the redis protocol faster than the pure JavaScript parser that is bundled with `redis`. You may see a similar thing with other modules that have optional dependencies like this. Typically if you see the module tree outline at the end of the console output, that means the module installation was successful.

Comment: Would you suggest me to use Linux based OS for Nodejs development or can I continue with Windows? Because when I'm done I'm going to put my website online on a Linux server.

Comment: Generally speaking Linux support is better as far as addon compatibility goes, but in cases like this one you can still develop on Windows since the `hiredis` dependency is optional. The only difference is performance.

Comment: As of 0.3.0 it seems [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis-node) does support windows...